# Check if all the required inputs are set before submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm wondering if there's a way to force a check for the required inputs on a form before submitting it programmatically using pure Javascript:

```
<form method="post" action="myController.php" id="myForm">
   <input type="text" id="input1" required>
   <input type="text" id="input2" required>
   <input type="text" id="input3" required>
   <input type="submit" onClick="return checkForm(event)" value="Save">
</form>
```

My Javascript file:

```
function checkForm(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // Some other stuff
   /*Prevalidate required inputs here*/
   document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}
```

I'm wondering if there's something like:

```
if(document.getElementById('myForm').valid()) {
   document.getElementById('myForm').submit()
}
```

Where the required inputs are checked just before submitting the form without the need to verify one by one directly by code.

Comment: You don't need to use JavaScript for this. Normal form submission checks the `required` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is the form.onSubmit event

But if you are using HTML 5, you can use `input.pattern` with a regular expression; submission will be blocked if the input doesn't pass the check and the `input` element will (on many browsers) get a red border around it.

Comment: Why doesn't `required` also work?

Comment: what do you think I think it does?

Comment: There's nothing in the question about matching a pattern, it just needs to be non-empty.

Comment: We can use pattern to check if the user enters only spaces which considered an empty input?

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi yes, like `\s*`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do something custom on submit you can trigger validation via [form.reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) and get back a boolean indicating whether all inputs have satisfied their constraints.

You can also listen for `invalid` events that will get fired for each invalid input during validation if you want to do something to flag them in the UI:

```js
function onInvalid (e) {
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');

document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('invalid', onInvalid);
});

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const valid = form.reportValidity();
})
```

```css
.invalid {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="test1" required />
  <input name="test2" required />
  <input name="test3" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take adventage of Form attribute *`onsumbit`* to submit the form if the value returned from the function `checkForm` which returns boolean value if all fields are filled and not empty dynamically.

```js
function checkForm(e) {
    let valid = true;
    inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="text"]')
    for(input of inputs){
      if(input.value.trim()==''){
        valid = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="myForm" action='test.php' onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
   <input type="text" id="input1" required>
   <input type="text" id="input2" required>
   <input type="text" id="input3" required>
   <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```